# java object comparison and inheritance

Tags: java, object, inheritance, comparison

Need your help with a practice question

how can i modify the below Bar class so that o.equals(0) returns false, you're not allowed to override  equals() inherited from the superclass?

```
 public class Scratchpad {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bar o = new Bar();
        System.out.println(o.equals(o));

    }
}

class Foo {
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return this == o;
    }
}

class Bar  extends Foo{

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `o.equals(o)` to return false?  Is this an academic exercise?

Comment: @NG That's a safe bet considering the very first line of the OP

Comment: So you want to know: how do I override equals without overriding equals?

Comment: yes this is an academic exercise, here's the full question if it helps// A class Foo has a method boolean equals(Object o) that simply returns the answer of the test 
this == o. Create a subclass Bar so that after the declaration Bar b = new Bar(); the call 
b.equals(b) returns false. To make this problem difficult, you are not allowed to override the 
equals method inherited from the superclass Foo.

Comment: This is awful, can I ask where this exercise came from? To say o does not equal o goes against any and all conventions. The answer is that you must edit the Foo class as Jeffrey says, but doing so in this way is appalling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can overload `equals`.

```
class Bar extends Foo{    
    public boolean equals(Bar b){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work if you do something like `Object o = new Bar(); o.equals(o);`

Comment: isn't this sort of overwritign equals()?

Comment: No it's overloading, that's a different thing. I'm pretty sure this is the correct answer.

Comment: @user3363135 No this is an overloading. And that's why it doesn't work if you use the snippet of code Jeffrey provided, because it will call the equals method in the Foo class. However looking at your assignment, I believe this is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you ever need to do this? I suppose you could with something like the following in `Foo`, but it breaks quite a few good design principles and could cause strange behavior later down the road if anyone else ever needs to use your code.

```
public final boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o.getClass() == Foo.class && this == o;
}
```

Note: This also breaks the contract for [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true.